# android best linter

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, lint

what is the more efficient linter which can be used with android studio? I need a fast one in which We can find with it kotlin and **xml** code smells

I tried the Android studio built in lint but it is too slow

Answer (score 1):

[Ktlint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwib8M7U09T4AhWJRmwGHWrnBpEQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplugins.jetbrains.com%2Fplugin%2F15057-ktlint-unofficial-&usg=AOvVaw3CxlNw7-Y5C6M77EYK3ktY) is pretty much awesome and works pretty fast for Kotlin. You can install it directly from the marketplace available inside Android Studio.

For `xml` would suggest to install [LayoutFormatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8299-layoutformatter)

Comment: this is just for kotlin I need for the xml

Comment: Added for xml as well

Comment: I need lint tools not formatters

Comment: I don't think so there is any for XML